# theorem numbering: section counter but remove the section number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems

I'm searching how to remove the chapter+section number on the theorem numbering with a section counter.

With no section counter it's like:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Title}
Chapter1
----Section 1
--------thm 1
--------thm 2
----Section 2
--------thm 3
--------thm 4
Chapter2
----Section 1
--------thm 5
--------thm 6
----Section 2
--------thm 7
--------thm 8
```

And with the section counter:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Title}[section]
Chapter 1
----Section 1
--------thm 1.1.1
--------thm 1.1.2
----Section 2
--------thm 1.2.1
--------thm 1.2.2
Chapter 2
----Section 1
--------thm 2.1.1
--------thm 2.1.2
----Section 2
--------thm 2.2.1
--------thm 2.2.2
```

And I want numbering my theorems like this:

```
\newtheorem????????
Chapter 1
----Section 1
--------thm 1
--------thm 2
----Section 2
--------thm 1
--------thm 2
Chapter 2
----Section 1
--------thm 1
--------thm 2
----Section 2
--------thm 1
--------thm 2
```

I know it's always a pain to remove such things, thanks for whoever will help me ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just re-define `\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Title}[section]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{one}
  \section{some}
  \begin{thm}
    Some theorem
  \end{thm}
  \begin{thm}
    Some theorem
  \end{thm}
  \section{some}
  \begin{thm}
    Some theorem
  \end{thm}
  \begin{thm}
    Some theorem
  \end{thm}
  \chapter{two}
  \section{some}
  \begin{thm}
    Some theorem
  \end{thm}
  \begin{thm}
    Some theorem
  \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]