# Fresh Numbering for theorems and Lemma in new chapter

Tags: random-numbers, number

I am building a report document. I want to start the numbering of lemmas and theorem with 1 in every new chapter.

For example, I have 3 Lemmas and 2 theorems in Chapter number 1. Now, in chapter 2 I again want to start with lemma 1 and theorem 1. But I don't want the format like Theorem 2.1

Can you please tell me the packages and how to achieve the above?

**Edit 1:** I want to This type of format

Chapter 1
    ----Section 1
    --------thm 1
    --------Lemma 1
    ----Section 2
    --------thm 2
    --------thm 3
    --------Remark 1
    Chapter 2
    ----Section 1
    --------Lemma 1
    --------thm 1
    ----Section 2
    --------thm 2
    --------Remark 1

But using the command `\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}` is not helpful for the Lemmas and Remarks. using the above command as `\renewcommand*{\theremark}{\arabic{remark}}` and similarly for lemmas either give an error or starts them with number 0. And sometimes ignores the command and starts with the number from the continuation itself i.e. If chapter 1 has 2 lemmas, then in chapter 2 it starts with lemma 3.

**Edit 2:** I have known [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273470/theorem-numbering-section-counter-but-remove-the-section-number) after @oliversm provided the answered this question.

**Edit 3:** Here is my implementation of what I am trying to say in Edit 1 as pointed out by @egreg

```
\documentclass[a4 paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{thm}{THEOREM}[chapter]
\renewcommand*{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}
\renewcommand*{\theremark}{\arabic{remark}}
\renewcommand*{\thelemma}{\arabic{lemma}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\section{Hi}
\begin{thm}
      some statement
\end{thm}
\section{ More Section in this chapter}
\begin{lemma}
      Purpose of Lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
      some bizzare statements
\end{proof}
\begin{remark}
      some useful statement
\end{remark}
\chapter{ Next one}
\section{in person}
\begin{lemma}
       It is the another lemma in the new chapter
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
       some tricky part
\end{proof}
\begin{thm}
       Theorem using previous lemma
\end{thm}
\begin{remark}
       exercise for reader
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Kumar If you don't show how you define your theorem-like environments, we cannot debug your code.

Comment: @Kumar Off topic, but I just had the "pleasure" of reading a paper with such a numbering system and it was very confusing and I had trouble finding anything. Please consider using a different format.

Answer (score 3):

> This is a close adaptation of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273475/106804) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311304/106804).

**Edit:**

> To respond to the OP and the inclusion of lemmas and remarks to follow the same style.

The following preamble I think achieves what you want:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand*{\thelemma}{\arabic{lemma}}
\renewcommand*{\theremark}{\arabic{remark}}
```

[image]

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand*{\thelemma}{\arabic{lemma}}
\renewcommand*{\theremark}{\arabic{remark}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}
Something.
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
Something.
\end{lemma}
\section{Second section}
\begin{theorem}
Something.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
Something.
\end{theorem}
\begin{remark}
Something.
\end{remark}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Another useful result}
\begin{lemma}
Something. 
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
Something else.
\end{theorem}
\section{Yet another section}
\begin{theorem}
Something.
\end{theorem}
\begin{remark}
Something.
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Kumar please provide the example of what you're trying.

Comment: @oliversm Shouldn't also `lemma` have `[theorem]`?

Comment: @egreg, I think it requires a `[chapter]` (which I missed) as it seems the OP wants the lemma and remarks and theorems to all be independent numberings.